# python: access past values in classes

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple game that is played best of five and where team B has a 60% chance of winning each round. Further, I want to simulate each game played X amount of times.

Ideally I would - after I have ran all the simulations - be able to access what happened in each simulation. E.g. who won the first round, who won the second etc in the most efficient way possible.

My idea was that I could append all of the data from the classes in a list and then access each one afterward. However, it doesn't work unless you append an actual value.

Below is a somewhat simplified example of the code:

```
class Game(object):

    def add_values(self):
        if random.random() > 0.6:
            Team.scoreA+=1
        else:
            Team.scoreB+=1

    def check_if_end(self):
        end = 0
        if max(Team.scoreA,Team.scoreB) == 3: end = 1
        return end

import random

class Team(object):

    def oriscore(self):
        Team.scoreA = 0
        Team.scoreB = 0

objdata = []
antsim = 200
for a in range(antsim):
    Team.oriscore(1)

    for i in range(5):
        Game.add_values(1)
        end = Game.check_if_end(1)
        if end == 1:
            objdata.append(Team)
            break

for i in objdata:
    print(i.scoreA,i.scoreB)
```

Printing out the below values will simply just show the result from the last simulation only. Whereas I want the result from each simulation.

In this specific game I could ofc just change it so that I append both scoreA and scoreB, however that doesn't seem so scaleable. So I wonder if there is a more efficient way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using class attributes for all of your values, and not using `self` anywhere? The way this is written, your classes aren't really doing anything useful—and that will make solving your problem harder.

Comment: In fact, if you wrote this on a more normal OO style, and took advantage of those classes, your problem would solve itself. You would, e.g., construct a new `team = Team()` and `game = Game(team)` each time through the loop, so `objdata.append(team)` would be building up a list of 200 different objects, instead of a list of the same object 200 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root problem here is that you aren't creating any instances. The only objects in your program (besides a few numbers) are the classes themselves. So you don't have anything to store in your list but the `Test` class object, which you append over and over, so you end up with a list of the same class object (which you keep on mutating) 200 times in a row.

What you want to do is create 200 *instances* `Team` instances, and store the attributes on those instances, and then you can have 200 *separate* objects in the list.

First, you have to make `Team` into a class that stores values on its instances:

```
class Team(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.scoreA = 0
        self.scoreB = 0
```

Now you have to do the same to `Game`. And, because each `Game` has to work with a `Team`, you need to give it one:

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, team):
        self.team = team

    def add_values(self):
        if random.random() > 0.6:
            self.team.scoreA += 1
        else:
            self.team.scoreB += 1

    def check_if_end(self):
        end = 0
        if max(self.team.scoreA, self.team.scoreB) == 3: end = 1
        return end
```

And now, your loop can create the separate instances. And then you can call methods on those instances, instead of calling them on the class and passing `1` as a fake `self`:

```
objdata = []
antsim = 200
for a in range(antsim):
    team = Team()   

    for i in range(5):
        game = Game(team)
        game.add_values()
        end = game.check_if_end()
        if end == 1:
            objdata.append(team)
            break
```

And now, instead of a list of 200 references to the `Team` class object, you have a list of 200 different `team` instances:

```
for team in objdata:
    print(team.scoreA, team.scoreB)
```

Comment: Good answer. The self.team = team solves a lot of issues.